# Composing type constructors like functions

Tags: haskell

I recently came across a situation where I wanted to be able to compose type constructors in an instance declaration. I would have liked to do this:

```
instance (SomeClass t, SomeClass t') => SomeClass (t . t') where
```

with `(t . t')` defined such that `(t . t') a = t (t' a)` (so `t` and `t'` have kind `* -> *`. We can partially apply type constructors, like functions, so what is the reason we cannot compose them? Also, is there perhaps a workaround for what I was trying to achieve? Perhaps with equality constraints?

(I do know that [Control.Compose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.6.7/docs/Control-Compose.html) exists, but it simply creates a `newtype` wrapper - I would like a type synonym).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (I do know that `Control.Compose` exists, but it simply creates a
>   `newtype` wrapper - I would like a type synonym).

This is not allowed in Haskell. A type synonym must be fully applied: you can't write `Compose t t'`, only `Compose t t' a`.

Allowing partially applied type synonyms would lead to type-level lambdas, which makes type inference undecidable, hence the lack of support for it in Haskell.

---

For instance, (enabling all the relevant GHC extensions)

```
type Compose t t' a = t (t' a)
data Proxy (k :: * -> *) = Proxy

pr :: Proxy (Compose [] [])
pr = Proxy
```

results in:

```
 Type synonym ‘Compose’ should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
    In the type signature for ‘pr’: pr :: Proxy (Compose [] [])
```

Similarly,

```
class C k where f :: k Int -> Int
instance C (Compose [] []) where f _ = 6
```

yields:

```
Type synonym ‘Compose’ should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
    In the instance declaration for ‘C (Compose [] [])’
```

Here's an example where type synonym partial application *is* allowed, instead (enabling `LiberalTypeSynonyms`):

```
type T k = k Int
type S = T (Compose [] [])

bar :: S -> S
bar = map (map succ)
```

Note however that this works only because after synonym expansion we get a fully applied type `[] ([] Int)` (i.e., `[[Int]]`). Roughly, this feature does not allow to do anything which one could have done without it, manually expanding the synonyms.

Comment: True, though `-XLiberalTypeSynonyms` does allow partially applied type synonyms, under some circumstances. Not in this case, however.

Comment: Great answer! The `type-level lambdas` was exactly the type of intuition I was looking for.

Comment: Type inference is undecidable with type level lambada.