# Haskell alternative class and empty function for guards

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Lets say I have the following ADT,

```
data Properties a = Property String a
    deriving (Show,Eq)
```

I have made the following instances for it,

```
instance Functor Properties where
  fmap f (Property name prop) = Property name (f prop)
--
instance Applicative (Properties) where
  pure a = Property "" a
  (Property _ f) <*> p = fmap f p

instance Monad (Properties) where
  return a = Property "" a
  (Property name prop) >>= f = (f prop)
```

So far so good. Let see what we can do so far,

```
pColors = Property "Color" ["Blue", "Red", "White"]
pNationality = Property "Nationality" ["Italian", "Norwegian", "Spanish"]

answers = do
  color <- fmap permutations pColors
  nation <- fmap permutations pNationality
  return $ zip color nation
```

gives,

```
*Main> answers
Property "" [(["Blue","Red","White"],["Italian","Norwegian","Spanish"]),(["Red","Blue","White"],["Norwegian","Italian","Spanish"]),(["White","Red","Blue"],["Spanish","Norwegian","Italian"]),(["Red","White","Blue"],["Norwegian","Spanish","Italian"]),(["White","Blue","Red"],["Spanish","Italian","Norwegian"]),(["Blue","White","Red"],["Italian","Spanish","Norwegian"])]
```

So `fmap` and the monadic bind are working as intended. Now I want to use the `guard` function from `alternative`. Basically I want to prune `pColors` and `pNationality` based on some predicates. So I try to define,

```
instance Alternative (Properties) where
  empty = Property "" []
```

But this gives me an error and I think (please correct me if I am wrong) that it is because Haskell is interpreting `[]` as different from `a`. But I thought `a` could be anything and `[]` is one of anything, so what is the problem?

Comment: You could do `newtype Properties a = Property (String, a) deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Applicative, Monad)` if you use `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}`

Comment: By itself or in conjunction with the ADT above? Assuming by itself (to avoid multiple declarations of `Property`) if I write `newtype Property a = String a deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Applicative, Monad)` gives an error that Functor can't be derived and have to use `DerivedFunctor`.

Comment: And adding `DerivedFunctor` the error then becomes, 

`Can't make a derived instance of ‘Applicative Property’
    (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
    cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough`

Comment: The `newtype` I recommended is a wrapper for the 2-tuple `(String, a)`. It produced no compiler errors in my testing. You don't need `DerivedFunctor`.

Comment: This type breaks the Applicative laws, doesn't it? That you are ignoring the left-most String in your definition of `(<*>)` set off alarm bells in my head, and the law it seems to break is the "[interchange](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:1)" law: `u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u`

Comment: Unfortunately it's [not possible to define an instance for `Property [a]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31018528/1048572). I would recommend distinguishing between `data Property a = Property String a` and `data Properties a = Properties String [a]` - the latter you can make an instance of `Alternative`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I thought `a` could be anything and `[]` is one of anything, so what is the problem?

It's not that `a` can be anything, but that `a` has to be able to be anything. That is if the user writes `x :: Property [a]; x = empty`, that has to be allowed, but `x :: Property Int; x = empty` has to be allowed as well. Your definition only allows the former, so it's incorrect.

There is no way to define a valid `empty` for your `Property` type unless you make it produce an error (like `empty = Property "" undefined`) or change the definition of `Property` to add a case for an empty property.

Comment: Thanks, is there a `Listable` type class constraint that I could give to `a`?

Comment: @IvanAbraham There's an [`IsList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList) typeclass, but there's no way to add `IsList a =>` as a constraint for `empty`. `Alternative` requires that *any* type can be used as the `a` in `f a`.

Comment: @4Castle Is it for use with `ConstraintKinds`? My aim is to define `Alternative` for the dataType. The `undefined` trick works with `empty` (will possible break something later). But for `<|>` I just want to do  `++` on the second element of the tuple (as in your previous comment).

Comment: @IvanAbraham If you want `<|>` to be `++`, then you must define your `Property` as `Property String [a]`.

Comment: @4castle That is how I began with this, but the `fmap` breaks down - since it needs `a -> a` and to map something like `permutation` won't be possible; will permute the list of strings as well as the strings themselves.

Comment: @IvanAbraham It looks to me like you're trying to create a blend of the `Identity` and list monad in one type. Instead, you should create two separate types as [Bergi recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045217/haskell-alternative-class-and-empty-function-for-guards#comment77065898_45045217).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148945/discussion-between-ivan-abraham-and-4castle).